# How can I change my code to print it out every time on new line?

Tags: java, sorting, collections

It is printing in a straight line, but I want it to print out every word on a new line.
This is what it looks like now `one, two, three`.

```
while (true) {
            String word = reader.readLine();
            if("end".equalsIgnoreCase(word)) {
                break;
            }
            list.add(word);
        }
        System.out.println(list);
```

Comment: Use a loop to iterate through your list and print each item in a single row using `System.out.println`.

Comment: its ArrayList<String>

Comment: @Predict_it Nevertheless, use for each. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no magic to this.  When you run println on an Object, it runs .toString() on that object.

```
    while (true) {
        String word = reader.readLine();
        if("end".equalsIgnoreCase(word)) {
            break;
        }
        list.add(word);
    }
    for (String word : list) {
        System.out.println(word);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the system.out.println(word) just after you add the words to your list.

```
while (true) {
            String word = reader.readLine();
            if("end".equalsIgnoreCase(word)) {
                break;
            }
            list.add(word);
           System.out.println(word);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

by adding something like:

```
   for (String word : list) {
   System.out.println(word);}
```

It's for-each loop iterating through all elements of list

Answer (score 0):

Use for-loop:

```
for(String word:list)
  System.out.println(word);
```

Or

```
for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
  System.out.println(list.get(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't want to repwhore, but this is how you would do that in 20 days after Java 8 comes out:

```
list.forEach(e -> System.out.println(e));
```

"e" represent particular String value in your list of String values.
I think it's just wort mentioning and quite sweet approach.

Comment: Or `list.forEach(System.out::println);`